# Error DESCRIPTION file does not exist. Can't upload shiny application on server

Tags: r, shiny, rsconnect

**When i try to deploy from Rstudio publishing button I get the following output**

```
RETICULATE_PYTHON_FALLBACK unset (no Python installation found)
[2023-07-19 19:35:42.73258] Deployment log started
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "C:/Users/Risha/Desktop/R_course/Developing_Data_Products/Course-Project-Shiny-Application-and-Reproducible-Pitch",      appFileManifest = "C:/Users/Risha/AppData/Local/Temp/4cfe-36ae-7387-13d1",      account = "8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal", server = "shinyapps.io",      appName = "Course_Project", appId = 9478584, launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE),      logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_India.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_India.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=English_India.utf8    

time zone: Asia/Calcutta
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1  cli_3.6.1       rsconnect_1.0.0 tools_4.3.1    
[5] rstudioapi_0.14 lifecycle_1.0.3 rlang_1.1.1    
── Preparing for deployment ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
[2023-07-19 19:35:42.912862] Inferring App mode and parameters
✔ Re-deploying "Course_Project" to "server: shinyapps.io / username: 8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal"
ℹ Looking up application with id "9478584"...
GET /v1/applications/9478584 1230ms
✔ Found application <https://8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal.shinyapps.io/Course_Project/>
[2023-07-19 19:35:44.294885] Bundling app dir
[2023-07-19 19:35:44.297429] Generate manifest.json
ℹ Bundling 1 file: 'app.r'
ℹ Capturing R dependencies with renv
----- Deployment error -----
Error in renv_snapshot_validate_report(valid, prompt, force) : 
  aborting snapshot due to pre-flight validation failure
Calls: <Anonymous> ... snapshotRenvDependencies -> <Anonymous> -> renv_snapshot_validate_report
 
----- Error stack trace -----
10: rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "C:/Users/Risha/Desktop/R_course/Developing_Data_Products/Course-Project-Shiny-Application-and-Reproducible-Pitch", 
        appFileManifest = "C:/Users/Risha/AppData/Local/Temp/4cfe-36ae-7387-13d1", 
        account = "8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal", server = "shinyapps.io", 
     ...
9: bundleApp(appName = target$appName, appDir = appDir, appFiles = appFiles, 
       appMetadata = appMetadata, quiet = quiet, verbose = verbose, 
       pythonConfig = pythonConfig, image = image)
8: createAppManifest(appDir = bundleDir, appMetadata = appMetadata, 
       users = users, pythonConfig = pythonConfig, retainPackratDirectory = TRUE, 
       image = image, verbose = verbose, quiet = quiet)
7: bundlePackages(bundleDir = appDir, extraPackages = extraPackages, 
       verbose = verbose, quiet = quiet)
6: computePackageDependencies(bundleDir, extraPackages, quiet = quiet, 
       verbose = verbose)
5: snapshotRenvDependencies(bundleDir, extraPackages, verbose = verbose)
4: renv::snapshot(bundleDir, prompt = FALSE)
3: renv_snapshot_validate_report(valid, prompt, force)
2: stop("aborting snapshot due to pre-flight validation failure")
1: (function (e) 
   {
       cat("----- Deployment error -----\n")
    ...
Error in renv_snapshot_validate_report(valid, prompt, force) : 
  aborting snapshot due to pre-flight validation failure
Calls: <Anonymous> ... snapshotRenvDependencies -> <Anonymous> -> renv_snapshot_validate_report
Execution halted
```

**On using `rsconnect::appDependencies()` I get the following output**

```
> rsconnect::appDependencies()
Error: DESCRIPTION file "C:/Users/Risha/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpyI8SfA/downloaded_packages/AppliedPredictiveModeling/DESCRIPTION" does not exist
```

**When using `deployApp()` I get the following error**

```
> deployApp()
── Preparing for deployment ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
This directory has been previously deployed in multiple places.
Which deployment do you want to use?
1: Course-Project-Shiny-Application-and-Reproducible-Pitch (server: shinyapps.io / username: 8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal):
<https://8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal.shinyapps.io/Course-Project-Shiny-Application-and-Reproducible-Pitch/>
2: Course_Project (server: shinyapps.io / username: 8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal):
<https://8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal.shinyapps.io/Course_Project/>
Selection: 1
✔ Re-deploying "Course-Project-Shiny-Application-and-Reproducible-Pitch" to "server: shinyapps.io / username: 8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal"
ℹ Looking up application with id "9478563"...
✔ Found application <https://8onzsa-rishav-dhariwal.shinyapps.io/Course-Project-Shiny-Application-and-Reproducible-Pitch/>
ℹ Bundling 1 file: app.r
ℹ Capturing R dependencies with renv
Error: DESCRIPTION file "C:/Users/Risha/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpyI8SfA/downloaded_packages/AppliedPredictiveModeling/DESCRIPTION" does not exist
```

**I am trying to project but am getting these errors. Can someone please help me resolve it,or what they mean?**